# How should I solve the following tensorflow package error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, package

I tried to import tensor flow after installing the package from the command prompt. I got this error:

> ERROR:root: Internal Python error in the inspect module.

Below is the traceback from this internal error.

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Answer (score -1):

Open a new anaconda prompt (close all running prompt), enter "pip install -q tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1" [From Michael Grogan.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750730/tensorflow-internal-python-error-module-not-found)