# Tensorflow Internal Python Error: Module not found

Tags: tensorflow

after I up-, down and sidegraded various versions of TensorFlow, it broke down and I had to reinstall everything, but somehow, I still can't get TensorFlow running...

Setup:
Anaconda3 2019-10
Windows 64 bit
Python 3.7.4
Tensorflow 2.1.0
pip 19.2.3

When importing some TensorFlow libraries, python doesn't find the modules as far as I can understand the error:

Code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Reshape, Dense, Flatten
```

Error:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-bb3d42a92014>", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Reshape, Dense, Flatten
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht   

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-bb3d42a92014>", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Reshape, Dense, Flatten
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2043, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1385, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1288, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1502, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1460, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-bb3d42a92014>", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Reshape, Dense, Flatten
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3249, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2043, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1385, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1288, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in structured_traceback
    formatted_exceptions += self.prepare_chained_exception_message(evalue.__cause__)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Felix Laptop\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2039                         # in the engines. This should return a list of strings.
-> 2040                         stb = value._render_traceback_()
   2041                     except Exception:

AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'!
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are using Windows with Python 3.7.4, then you may be running into some compatibility issues with TensorFlow. When I use Python 3.6.9, pip installs TensorFlow 2.0 without issue: !pip install -q tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, unfortunately.

Comment: I ran Michael Grogan's tip at Anaconda Power Shell Prompt, it ran ~10 minutes. And the error disappeared. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to resolve the issue. But you can follow the configuration written below to resolve this issue. Here in `TF>2.0.0` some DLL issues will arise.

```
Python<=3.6.9
CUDA==10.0
CuDNN==7.6 or 7.4
2.x => TF >= 1.14
```

Else you can use Google Colab to use the same configuration.
I hope it'll help.